# Where is the function 'define' defined in this codebase?

Tags: javascript, amd

I was looking through [file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)'s javascript code.

There is a [piece of code](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L15-L27) which checks if define is a function and declares a few dependencies i guess

```
(function (factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
        define([
            'jquery',
            'jquery.ui.widget'
        ], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals:
        factory(window.jQuery);
    }
}
```

The comments just above the code says define is global.  But i dont have it in my application built using angularjs.

I searched the codebase for declaration of define.  BUt couldn't find any.  I googled for AMD and i could see define being [used here](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#definition) again.

My question is where is 'define' defined?

Comment: Read http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/ and https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define` is a function whose functionality is defined by [the Asynchronous Module Definition spec­if­i­cat­ion](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD). AMD is just a spec; there's multiple implementations, of which RequireJS is one. You could see how RequireJS implements it if you want, but keep in mind that RequireJS's `define` isn't the only `define` out there.

Comment: I will go through the link.  One more question remains.  Where is 'define' defined in https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload . As far as i explored, i couldn't find requirejs in that codebase. There are only two plugins. xdr-transport and postmessage.transport in that codebase.

Comment: @R.A.J: I'm guessing that it *isn't* defined — that code exists only to detect if you *already have* an AMD implementation like RequireJS, and if you do, automatically play well with it. If you have no AMD implementation already, it doesn't do anything. (it takes the other branch of the `if`)